# PHP transform associative array of string in tree structure

Tags: php, tree

I have a list of path (just strings), like this:

```
$data = array(
    array('path' => 'foo/bar/baz'),
    array('path' => 'foo/bar/baz/qux'),
    array('path' => 'foo/bar'),
    array('path' => 'bar/baz/foo'),
    array('path' => 'baz'),
);
```

I would like to achieve a structure like this

```
Array
(
    [foo] => Array
        (
            [bar] => Array
                (
                    [baz] => Array
                        (
                            [qux] => null
                        )
                )
        )
    [bar] => Array
        (
            [baz] => Array
                (
                    [foo] => null
                )
        )
    [baz] => null
)
```

Side note

1. the structure displays only, non-common portions
2. the leaf would be `null` (`null` for me would be without children)

I know you will ask me [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) the problem is: 
I don't know how to deal the problem in the right way

can you give me some advice, without massacre of downvote?

Comment: I don't see the pattern behind the array and the expected output. Because at the end you create: `[baz] =>` but you already have one that begins with this.

Comment: @Rizier123 the leaf would be `null` (`null` for me would be without children)

Comment: You're trying to convert that array as it is into the desired array, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got pretty close, but instead of the endings being `null`, they're array's with size 0.

```
<?php

function ProcessPath($entry,$depth,&$current)
{
  if($depth<count($entry))
  {
    $key = $entry[$depth];
    if(!isset($current[$key]))$current[$key] = null;
    ProcessPath($entry,$depth+1,$current[$key]);
  }
}


$data = array(
  array('path' => 'foo/bar/baz'),
  array('path' => 'foo/bar/baz/qux'),
  array('path' => 'foo/bar'),
  array('path' => 'bar/baz/foo'),
  array('path' => 'baz'),
);
$result = null;
foreach($data as $path)
{
  ProcessPath(explode("/",$path['path']),0,$result);
}

print_r($result);

?>
```

output

```
Array
(
    [foo] => Array
        (
            [bar] => Array
                (
                    [baz] => Array
                        (
                            [qux] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [bar] => Array
        (
            [baz] => Array
                (
                    [foo] => 
                )

        )

    [baz] => 
)
```

Essentially the function ProcessPath takes:

- An array of the split path
- The current depth eg: `[foo]` (0) or `foo > [bar]` (1) or `foo > bar > [baz]` (2)
- A reference to where on the array the path is being put (denoted by `&$reference`

First off the function checks if the depth is within the current path being processed.

Then it extracts the `$key` to simplify the rest of the code.

This is where the magic happens, if the output hasn't got the current path segment set, it sets it.

The last line recurses onto the next element in the path `$entry` by taking the same `$entry`, increasing the `$depth` by 1, and changing the `$current` to the new section `$current[$key]`.

Comment: If this doesn't work, just change `[]` to `array()` (could be a language error)

Comment: thank you very much. I edited the answer to support old versions of php

Comment: @SimoneNigro I just added a description to it so it probably would've cleared your edit. I added the `array()s` back in

Comment: Aight I redid my edit again (didn't know that you could just whack a `null` in there). Should give you the desired output now

Comment: is perfect, [I tried it](http://codepad.org/h5BxRQEv) and it does exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is iterate over the paths, explode the string of each path, and then add each value to the new array depending on the position of the value. If the value is the first, then it'll be the base. If it's the 2nd, then it goes in as a new array inside the first one, and so on.